# How to Convert an Array to JSON on bases on keys like java packages to give a look of tree view

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

My question is about how to Convert Array to JSON on bases of keys like packages.

I have this array as initial

```
$scope.myValues = [
{
    title:"Transportation",
    id:"1",
    moduleId:"transportation"
},
{
    title:"Bus",
    id:"1.1",
    moduleId:"transportation.bus"
},
{
    title:"Tata Motors",
    id:"1.1.1",
    moduleId:"transportation.bus.tata.motors"
},
{
    title:"Ashok Leyland",
    id:"1.1.2",
    moduleId:"transportation.bus.ashok.leyland"
},
{
    title:"Eicher Motors",
    id:"1.1.3",
    moduleId:"transportation.bus.eicher.motors"
},
{
    title:"Train",
    id:"1.2",
    moduleId:"transportation.train"
},
{
    title:"The Himalayan Queen",
    id:"1.2.1",
    moduleId:"transportation.train.himQueen"
},
{
    title:"Maharaja Deccan Odyssey",
    id:"1.2.2",
    moduleId:"transportation.train.maharaja.deccan"
},
{
    title:"Darjeeling Himalayan Railway",
    id:"1.2.3",
    moduleId:"transportation.train.darjeeling.himalayan"
}
];
```

and I want my final array sorted based on keys, like packages keys in java.

```
$scope.myValues = [{
title:"Transportation",
moduleId:"transportation",
category:[{
    title:"Bus",
    moduleId:"transportation.bus",
    category:[{
        title:"Tata Motors",
        moduleId:"transportation.bus.tataMotors",
        },{
        title:"Ashok Leyland",
        moduleId:"transportation.bus.ashokLeyland",
        },{
        title:"Eicher Motors",
        moduleId:"transportation.bus.eicherMotors",
        }
    ]
},{
    title:"Train",
    moduleId:"transportation.train",
    category:[{
        title:"The Himalayan Queen",
        moduleId:"transportation.train.himQueen",
        },{
        title:"Maharaja Deccan Odyssey",
        moduleId:"transportation.train.maharajaDeccan",
        },{
        title:"Darjeeling Himalayan Railway",
        moduleId:"transportation.train.darjeelingHimalayan",
        }
    ]
}];
```

I have keys like indexing.
My aim is to make a json format object, with a hierarchy structure based on indexing.
Any suggestion no how to convert this array to array like JSON format.

Comment: First you transform the source array into the format and order you've shown. Then turning it into JSON is just using `JSON.stringify()` on the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this tree by looping over the data once.

- Start with an empty array for our new format
- Check out the first item

  - Split its id by `.` and cast the path elements to indexes
  - Split the numeric path in to the last index, and the path towards it
- Create a new item, for now without a `category` property
- Navigate through the new format using the numeric path, creating `category` arrays along the way when needed
- When you've reached the deepest/final layer, add to the array using the last index

```js
const data = [{title:"Transportation",id:"1",moduleId:"transportation"},{title:"Bus",id:"1.1",moduleId:"transportation.bus"},{title:"Tata Motors",id:"1.1.1",moduleId:"transportation.bus.tata.motors"},{title:"Ashok Leyland",id:"1.1.2",moduleId:"transportation.bus.ashok.leyland"},{title:"Eicher Motors",id:"1.1.3",moduleId:"transportation.bus.eicher.motors"},{title:"Train",id:"1.2",moduleId:"transportation.train"},{title:"The Himalayan Queen",id:"1.2.1",moduleId:"transportation.train.himQueen"},{title:"Maharaja Deccan Odyssey",id:"1.2.2",moduleId:"transportation.train.maharaja.deccan"},{title:"Darjeeling Himalayan Railway",id:"1.2.3",moduleId:"transportation.train.darjeeling.himalayan"}];

const addModule = (arr, { title, moduleId, id }) => {
  const entry = { title, moduleId }; 
  const path = id.split(".").map(Number).map(n => n - 1);
  
  const targetIndex = path[path.length - 1];
  const indexes = path.slice(0, -1);
  
  const loc = indexes.reduce(
    (arr, i) => {
      const next = arr[i];
      if (!next.category) next.category = [];
      return next.category;
    },
    arr
  );
  
  loc[targetIndex] = entry;
  return arr;
}

console.log(
  data.reduce(addModule, [])
);
```